# What key combination quits vimtutor without saving any changes made?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

What key combination quits vimtutor without saving any changes made?

Enter control keys in uppercase, for example:
- use ESC for escape
- use "+" (without space between keys) to show a key combination

for example CTRL+d or CTRL+d! (Do not use spaces between multiple keys).

Comment: What Ubuntu product are you using?  Is it really Ubuntu 12.04 as you've tagged?

Answer (score 0):

`vimtutor` involves nothing more than having a tutorial textfile open in `vim`. So you close without saving the way it works in vim, and the way it is thought in vimtutor

<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>!<kbd>Return</kbd>

So you give the command `:q!` ("quit even if the work is not saved"). If you are in INSERT mode, first hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch to command mode.